# How to use Azure AD to generate tokens with role definition

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory

I have this scenario: I have an App Service, I set its authorization as Allow Anonymous Request and the Authentication Provider as Active Directory setting an Azure AD App.

In this AD App I put in its manifest some roles like this one:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Approver",
      "id": "8f29f99b-5c77-4fba-a310-4a5c0574e8ff",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Approvers can mark documents as approved",
      "value": "approver"
    },
```

Posting to the URL https://login.windows.net//oauth2/token with my AD App ID I receive a token and what I expected to was to find the role in this token. It doesn't work like this and I couldn't find out the reason.

What I want is to generate the token using Azure and in my API, to set an [Authorize(Role="approver")] to filter controllers accessed by different clients using the same tenant.

Comment: Have you assigned this role to the user whom you are requesting a token for?

Comment: @juunas To get the token I pass the APP ID and a secret. The grant type is client_credentials and the resource.

Comment: Yeah, well, this is an app role that can be assigned on a user. The token you get is for your app, not for a user. Thus it cannot have the role in it.

Comment: @juunas How to get the role in the app token? I tryed to put allowedMemberTypes as Application too.

Comment: Yeah, what you are then doing is adding an app permission. Now then the calling application must be granted that app permission. You can do that in the Azure Portal. Once that is done you should get the role in tokens.

Comment: @juunas do you mean by setting the AD as autentication provider and configuring it with this AD app? If so, I have it already done without success too.

Comment: Well, you would need to make another app in Azure AD to assign it this permission. Then you can get the token with *its* credentials.

Answer (score 2):

If your scenario is about assigning application role the user/group . Once a user is assigned to an application role (either through a direct assignment or via an assignment to a group that the user is member of), Azure AD includes the roles claim in the token when the user signs in to the application. The application can then authorize the user using constructs like IsInRole(“reader”) or the [Authorize (Roles=”reader”)] of .net. You should make :

```
"allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
```

Then you don't need to use client credential flow . And [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) is an article about how to config that , also refer to code sample [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/) .

If your scenario is about allowing web applications and web APIs that act as clients and access other resource APIs, to request for application roles of resource API to be assigned to them(using client credential flow). The role gets assigned to the client app when it is installed by the Azure AD customers. You could refer to below steps to achieve that :

1. create a new ad application in classic azure ad portal :
   [image]
2. Set the sign-on url and app id url .
3. On the configure tab scroll down to the section called ‘permissions to other application’. Here, add a new permission by first selecting the API for which the client application is requesting an application role, and then selecting the desired application role in the Application Permissions drop down. In my API app(name is testRole) , i have set the roles like :
   [image]

Then select application role :
[image]

4. Then we could acquire the token to let my web app access the “testRole” API using client credential flow :

   Post https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant/oauth2/token

   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   resource=http%3A%2F%2Ftestbasic1.onmicrosoft.com%2Ftestrole&client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials
5. Then the access token will include the app role :
   [image]

You could read more about Roles based access control in cloud applications using Azure AD from [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/)

**EDIT**

To set permission to other application in new portal:
1. click azure ad icon in left panel , select the web app , click the **Required permissions** , click Add, Select an API , then search the API you want to access :
[image]

2. Then select the application permissions you want :
   [image]

Comment: Nan Yu, do you have this same example using the new azure portal? I have some limitations to access the classic. Until step 3 I accomplished. I don't know how select the App Role like you show in the imagem.

Comment: @ Leandro Lima, i have edit my answer , please check that .

Comment: @ Leandro Lima, have you solved your problem ,any update ?

Comment: Nan Yu, I haven't tested yet, I'll test and answer you later.

Comment: It seems like the new portal no longer has the section called ‘permissions to other application’. This information probably has to be updated in the manifest, but I cannot find out how. Do you know what should be put in the application manifest of the API in the new Azure Portal?

Comment: @JohannesBrodwall , to assign role  , you need go to the `Enterprise applications` blade , see document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal) .

Comment: Can this be done in Web Forms? I've an app that would take several weeks to change to MVC yet need this to work :).

Comment: @RichardGriffiths , Yes, the claim is in access token , it doesn't care you are using web forms or MVC

Comment: I really should add an answer somewhere on SO how we did this in webforms - we did add roles, on the azure side and yep, could access them in the Claims side in the app itself.