# Azure Active Directory RBAC Not Returning Roles in Bearer Token

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, rbac

I'm using the Azure AD Basic tier with an ASP.NET Core API, I've followed the [RBAC sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims). I've set up an application with roles in my manifest like so:

```
appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [ "User" ],
      "displayName": "Read Device",
      "id": "b2e6f6c2-c3d5-4721-ad49-0eea255ccf45",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Can read a device.",
      "value": "read_device"
    },
    ...
]
```

I've setup my API to use the `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` middleware like so:

```
application.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Azure Active Directory",
        Authority = options.Authority,
        Audience = options.ClientId,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RoleClaimType = "roles",
            ValidateIssuer = false
        }
    })
```

I've given my user the above 'Read Device' role:

[image]

I'm using Swagger UI to make the call to get the auth token. It calls the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?
    response_type=token
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5100%2Fswagger%2Fo2c.html
    &realm=-
    &client_id=[Client ID]
    &scope=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fws%2F2008%2F06%2Fidentity%2Fclaims%2Frole
    &state=oauth2
    &resource=[Client ID]
```

I suspected that I am not passing the correct values to the `scope` parameter, so I have tried asking for every `scope` I can think of:

```
&scope=openid
    %20email
    %20profile
    %20offline_access
    %20user_impersonation
    %20roles
    %20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fws%2F2008%2F06%2Fidentity%2Fclaims%2Frole
    %20read_device
```

If I set `"groupMembershipClaims": "All"` in my manifest I can see group claims but I want roles instead. I'm able to login to call my API, however I never get any roles back in my JWT token, so I'm unable check the users role. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've assigned the user to the app with that role?

Comment: How are you getting the access token? Could you show that? If it is a delegated call with authorization code grant flow or similar then it should work..

Comment: @juunas Updated question with the code snippet.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong on that side, but how are you actually generating an access token on the calling side?

Comment: @junnas I've updated the URL I call to get the auth token. I suspect, I'm not passing the correct values to the `scope` parameter. What should go there?

Comment: I tried messing with the `scope` parameter, passing every scope I can think of but nothing so far. Question updated once again.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I needed to request an `id_token` instead of a `token`. An `id_token` contains extra claims/scopes/resources about the user. I also needed to provide a `nonce` parameter containing a new random GUID on every request. Thus, I ended up with the following URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?
    response_type=id_token
    &client_id=[Client ID]
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2F
    &nonce=9ac5ad8d-df44-48e6-9bd6-e72743b3625c
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are want to enable the role be assigned to users or groups(allowedMemberTypes=User) :

1. If you want to perform authorization using role claims , you could
   follow the steps in this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) , you could find the roles
       claim is in the **id_token**  .
2. If you want to make a client app to call your web api , when user
   sign in ,app could check the access rules based on the role
       claim,
           you could use delegate flow(OAuth Authorization Code Grant,Implicit
           Grant Flow..),roles claim is in the **access_token** ;

If you want to specify the role be assigned to client applications(allowedMemberTypes=Application), you could use OAuth Client Credential Flow ,appRoles of resource app/api that are assigned to the client app, and you will find the roles claim in the **access_token** ,check the detail steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42664492/5751404).

Please click [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) for more details .

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had mistakenly configured the App Registration to emit Security Groups as roles claims, thus overwriting the App Roles from the manifest. Removing the optional groups claim and logging back in correctly emitted the App Roles names in the `roles` claim of the `id_token`.